# MySQL check if number is in a string field (with numbers separated by comma)

Tags: mysql

In my table I've subcategories like

```
id, name, subcat
1, "john", "4,8,34"
2, "jimmy", "8,32,4"
3, "elthon", "42"
```

How to do something like
`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 8 IN (subcat)`?

Comment: This becomes *a lot* easier if you model your data to store values separately.  Relational databases are good at that sort of thing.

Comment: If it's not too late, change your data model. Do not store comma-separated lists in a single field. Store them in a separate table. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do here? I can't quite grasp what output you're trying to get.

Comment: **`FIND_IN_SET`** function ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: There are more tables with inner join so I prefer maintaining subcategories like this to avoid complications.

Awesome @spencer7593, it works!

Comment: @akklv3r: `"I prefer maintaining subcategories like this to avoid complications"` - Except that you just encountered a complication which doesn't happen with properly modeled data.  You've invented a problem to solve, which is the very definition of making things unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first want to mention.... storing comma separated lists is a SQL AntiPattern. I recommend Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent book "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming. Avaiable at Amazon and other fine booksellers [[https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

---

To answer the question you asked... with well formed lists, we can use the MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function. As a demonstration

```
    FIND_IN_SET('8','4,8,34')
```

evaluates to TRUE.

Reference: [`FIND_IN_SET` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

---

If we want to avoid using the MySQL specific `FIND_IN_SET` function, we could use a LIKE comparison. But to get that to work, we need to add a comma character at the beginning and end of the subcat list, and then search for a comma delimited value, e.g. **`',8,'`** in the list. For example

```
 CONCAT(',',subcat,',') LIKE '%,8,%'
```

Comment: Thank you, FIND_IN_SET do the job. I know it's not the best practice but nothing compared to the code that I have to rewrite because now is very obsolete (not directly for my fault)